# Add Annotations in MapKit - Programmatically

Tags: swift, mapkit, swift3, mkpointannotation

I am trying to add annotations to my map.
I have an array of points with coordinates inside.
I am trying to add annotations from those coordinates.

I have this defined:

```
var points: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]() 
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
```

points has coordinates inside. I checked. And I do this:

```
for index in 0...points.count-1 {
        annotation.coordinate = points[index]
        annotation.title = "Point \(index+1)"
        map.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
```

It keeps adding only the last annotation... Instead of all of them.
Why is this?
By the way, is there a way to delete a specified annotation, by title for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each annotation needs to be a new instance, you are using only one instance and overriding its coordinates. So change your code:

```
for index in 0...points.count-1 {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()  // <-- new instance here
    annotation.coordinate = points[index]
    annotation.title = "Point \(index+1)"
    map.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try it in a couple of hours and report.  Is it possible to dele te annotations by title?

Comment: To delete an annotation just iterate over the `map.annotations` array until you found the annotation. Then call `map.removeAnnotation(annotation)`

Answer (score 5):

You can edit your for loop with the below code 
I think your array would be like points array

```
  let points = [
    ["title": "New York, NY",    "latitude": 40.713054, "longitude": -74.007228],
    ["title": "Los Angeles, CA", "latitude": 34.052238, "longitude": -118.243344],
    ["title": "Chicago, IL",     "latitude": 41.883229, "longitude": -87.632398]
]
for point in points {   
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = point["title"] as? String
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: point["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: point["longitude"] as! Double)
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

it's working for me. All the best for you.